How to run script with Different IP Addres everytime when my chrome is launched
I need one help
Problem Statement
Run script of webDriverIo with Different IP Addres everytime when my chrome is launched
Framework Used
WebdriverIo/Cucumber
package.json
{
"name": "webdriverio-tests",
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "",
"private": true,
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^7.25.4",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.25.4",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.25.4",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.25.4",
    "chromedriver": "^123.0.3",
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.5.0",
    "geckodriver": "^4.2.0",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.0.0",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^4.4.3"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.8.0",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "is-reachable": "^5.2.1",
    "jsonpath": "^1.1.1",
    "properties-parser": "^0.3.1",
    "sync-request": "^6.1.0"
}

}
wdio.config.js
I will show the code that was used only for this purpose
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

const proxyList = [
 "http://2001:470:1:1ab::2",
 //"http://proxy2.example.com",
 //"http://proxy3.example.com",
 // Add more proxy URLs as needed
]

async function isValidProxy(proxyUrl) {
 const protocol = proxyUrl.startsWith('https') ? https : http;

 return new Promise(resolve => {
 protocol.get(proxyUrl, res => {
 if (res.statusCode === 200) {
 resolve(true); // Proxy is reachable
 } else {
 resolve(false); // Proxy is unreachable
 }
 }).on('error', () => {
 resolve(false); // Error occurred, proxy is unreachable
 });
 });
}

function getDynamicProxy() {
 // Choose a random proxy URL from the list
 const randomProxy = proxyList[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxyList.length)];
 return randomProxy;
}


 onPrepare: async function (config, capabilities) {
 if (capabilities && capabilities.length > 0) {
 // Assuming you have a function to get a dynamic proxy URL
 const dynamicProxy = getDynamicProxy();

 // Check if the dynamic proxy is reachable
 const proxyIsValid = await isValidProxy(dynamicProxy);

 if (proxyIsValid) {
 // Set httpProxy for each capability
 capabilities.forEach(capability => {
 capability.proxy.httpProxy = dynamicProxy;
 });

 console.log("Proxy IP address:", dynamicProxy);
 } else {
 console.error('Invalid proxy IP:', dynamicProxy);
 // Handle the case of an invalid proxy IP here
 }
 } else {
 console.log("No capabilities configured.");
 }

 // Clean up directories
 removeSync("json");
 removeSync("reports");
 },

Feature file
Feature: Sample Feature
 
  Scenario: Login
    Given I am launching "https://login.salesforce.com/"
    When I wait for "5000"

Request to please help so that achieve business requirement

Hello Folks , please do reply if u know the solution
